# Is it possible to access a local host api from an online web app?

Tags: web, localhost, backend, webapi

I have a hosted web app on Digital Ocean configured with Nginx.

I need to access a fingerprint scanner webapi running locally on localhost:8000 from that online hosted web app.

Is it possible to do that without tunneling the localhost? If I only want to access it from the same computer (running both the online web app and the localhost webapi), I don’t want the localhost to be publicly accessible to other computers.

Thank you.

I tried using the ip4 public ip, but that didn’t work, maybe because of firewall, but I’m not sure what to do.